# How can I include records based on when they first appear, and exclude other records based on a certain date?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to select criteria based on inclusions and exclusions of the same attributes and on different dates and I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to do this.  Here is a list of my criteria.

1. The record was first added to the database with a transaction of 222 or 223 and an activity code of ‘A’.
2. The record does not have a status code of 7
3. Any records where the latest activity code (A, V, W, J) for the following transactions (109, 154, 982, 745) after 10/01/2009 should not be included in the results,

   There are 2 tables involved with a join on the employee ID.

Table 1:

```
|id  |  statcode
|  1     |  1
|  2     |  3
|  3     |  7
|  4     |  2
```

Table 2:

```
|id       |  date      | act_code   |  trans 
|   1     |  1/1/17    |   Z        |    109
|   1     |  3/4/12    |   A        |    222
|   1     |  2/14/09   |   A        |    154
|   2     |  1/1/17    |   A        |    223
|   2     |  6/6/13    |   V        |    109
|   3     |  11/23/14  |   A        |    222
|   4     |  12/13/16  |   X        |    154
|   4     |  11/23/14  |   W        |    223
```

What I’d like to return is:

```
|    id  | statcode|  date      | act_code   |  trans 
|   1    |   1     |  3/4/12    |   A        |    222
```

ID 2 would not be selected because the first trans is not one of the correct values. ID 3 would not be included due to a incorrect status code. ID 4 would not be selected because the latest act_code is not one of the correct values. Anyone have an idea as to how to go about this? Thanks in advance.

edit: Here is the query as attempted. It seems to return everything.

```
SELECT *
FROM firsttable a
join secondtable b on a.id=b.id
where exists (select id, min(date) from
secondtable 
where c.TRANS in ('222','223') and (TRANS NOT IN ('109', '154', '982', 
'745')
AND ACT_CODE NOT IN  ('A', 'V', 'W', 'J') and date>= to_date('10/01/2009', 
'MM/DD/YYYY'))
group by id)
and a.statcode <> '07'  
;
```

Comment: Your just saying where a record exists in the 2nd query, if it returns a single row it will return everything from the fist part. You need to add a clause for secondtable.id = a.id to force it to filter the 2nd part by the id being returned in the 1st

Comment: If your question was answered you should mark it as such to help others identify a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
select Emp_id,statcode,date,act_code,trans
from table1 A join table2 b on (a.id=b.id) 
WHERE b.trans in(222,223)
AND b.act_code='A'
AND a.stat_code<>7
AND (SELECT NVL(max(date),TO_DATE('01-JAN-1990','DD-MON-YYYY'))
       FROM table2 c 
       WHERE c.id=b.id
         AND c.act_code in ('A', 'V', 'W', 'J')
         AND c.trans IN (109, 154, 982, 745)) <  TO_DATE('01-OCT-1990','DD-MON-YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

*Updated: now tested and working.

```
SELECT * FROM
tbl1 a INNER JOIN tbl2 b on a.id = b.id
where b.trans IN (222,223) 
AND a.statcode <> 7
AND b.act_code = 'A'
AND NOT EXISTS(
SELECT 1 from tbl2 t2
    WHERE t2.id = a.id 
    AND t2.act_code IN ('A','V','W','J')
    AND t2.trans IN (109,154,982,745)
    AND t2."date" > to_date('10/01/2009', 'MM/DD/YY'));
GO
```